# Calculating percentage from two columns involving conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to calculate the percentage of individuals that meet the following conditions:

- Priority A had a meeting time (defined as the difference between starttime and endtime) > 5
- Priority B meeting time > 10
- Priority C meeting time > 15

In each case the denominator is the total number of individuals that have the same priority.

```
ID Priority StartTime EndTime Location 
1 A 2011-04-23 12:34 2011-04-23 9:50 AA
2 B 2011-04-21 1:23 2011-05-17 8:45 BB
3 C 2011-04-23 12:34 2011-04-23 9:50 AA
4 C 2011-04-23 12:34 2011-04-23 9:50 AA
5 B 2011-04-23 12:34 2011-04-23 9:50 BB
6 C 2011-04-23 12:34 2011-04-23 9:50 AA
7 A 2011-04-23 12:34 2011-04-23 9:50 BB
8 B 2011-04-23 12:34 2011-04-23 9:50 BB
9 A 2011-04-23 12:34 2011-04-23 9:50 AA
10 A 2011-04-23 12:34 2011-04-23 9:50 AA
```

Here is the matrix output that I need (sorry not sure how to add tables in stackoverflow):

Priority  AA BB TotalR

A 35% 35% 35% 35%

B 35% 35% 35% 35%

C 35% 35% 35% 35%

TotalB 35% 35% 35% 35%

So for example, in cell A-AA, that represents the percentage of all priority A cases for location AA that had a meeting time greater than 5.

TotalR is the percentage of all cases in locations AA and BB that had a meeting time greater than 5.

TotalB is the percentage of all individuals with a priority A, B, or C designation that had a meeting time greater than their respective cut-offs (i.e. 5, 10, 15).

Note that the numbers in the matrix are purely for illustration and are not accurate.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Show the results that you want.

Comment: See .....,, edited for illustrative purposes